# How to take my bike from Germany and/or France to Switzerland?

Tags: trains, switzerland, bicycles

This summer I want to take my bike from Germany and/or France in the area around Cologne to Switzerland in the area around Zurich. For this purpose, I have a couple of things I want to make sure before:

- Can I take my bike in every train or are there special trains I'm not allowed to take my bike with me?
- Do I always have to buy an extra ticket for my bike?
- In Switzerland, there is a great service that allows you to dropoff your bike at any station and the pick it up the next day at any other station for something around 20 CHF. Does such a great service also exist on international trains between Germany and Switzerland?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I take my bicycle into all German trains?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16068/can-i-take-my-bicycle-into-all-german-trains)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. You can take your bike along in most trains, but not in the ICE. It's probably best to check when you look up the connection online (you can even use it as a search criterium).
2. In some local trains you don't need an extra ticket. It seems to [depend on all kinds of factors](http://www.bahn.de/p/view/service/fahrrad/mitnahme/preise_fahrradmitnahme.shtml), including the time of day. In [regional and national trains](http://www.bahn.de/p/view/service/fahrrad/mitnahme/07rad_fahrradzuege.shtml), you always need a ticket for your bike as well as a reservation.
3. Yes, [there is such a service](http://www.bahn.de/p/view/service/fahrrad/rad_kuriergepaeck.shtml). It costs 25.50 EUR per bike, and an additional 8 EUR for international delivery (only to Luxembourg, Austria and Switzerland). Note that the bike has to be wrapped (you can order a wrapping for 5.90 EUR).